# User Profile Service and Account disabled

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, user-accounts, managed-account

I'm facing a problem after I have installed and configured the User Profile Service.

When I create the synch everything work fine but now the system floods active directory with wrong credential (I suppose) and this make AD lock the account...

Any suggestion? I remember I can see the AD folders so I think credentials are right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are absolutely critical with UPS... permissions, and doing the configuration in the right order. Spence Harbar has the 'gold standard' guide on [how to setup UPS](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)... follow it to the letter.

Remember that when FIM is provisioned, it does so under the farm account, but the service should execute as another identity, and the synchronization as a dedicated synchronization identity. If the service account is changed (via Central Admin -> Configure Service Accounts) at any time after FIM has been configured and setup, you likely will need to reconfigure/reprovision UPS (it's just not very forgiving).

If you're seeing a flood of hits that result in the account being locked, it's entirely possible that the service running FIM has the wrong credentials (that's a managed account, so you can reset the password via CA). It's also entirely possible that the physical sync account (not a managed account) has either the wrong credentials, or not the correct delegated authority to Active Directory.

Are you doing one way sync, or bi-directional sync?

You can also run the FIM management console on the box running the UPS service, and review the FIM logs to see where it's blowing up.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I try to follow the guide.. I think I need only one way.. I'm a real newbye in config services!

Comment: Follow Spence's guide to the letter and you won't have any issues :-)

Comment: Mmm I'm facing a problem: I created all, services are running but even if I see users from people picker and from "configure synch" when I search with Manage User Profile it tells me I have 0 account even if I do a full synch! Any suggestion?

Comment: Seeing users in the people picker is completely unrelated to UPS Sync. Have you selected containers on the configure profile connections page? If it's running a full sync and not pulling users in, it is likely blowing up during the connection to AD... check AD delegation of the Sync account.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the account you chose at the time of Sync Connection. The page does not validate the password, it just checks that the two boxes are the same.

M